# Bayesian Hyperparameter Optimization. What makes it "bayesian"?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, hyperparameter

I'm using some bayesian hyperparameter optimization. I know how they works
.

They always calculate the next values of the hyperparameter dependent on the result of former evaluations.

But what makes them bayesian? I know the bayesian theorem is:

```
p(A|B) = (P(B|A) * P(A)) / P(B)
```

What is the connection between this formula an the process of bayesian hyperparameter optimization?
Is it just that the probability of a hyperparameter value depends on condition (former evaluations) we consider as relevant for the event?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The previous evaluations indeed act as defining the prior distribution.